# Scenario step to find out terraform version

Tags: testing, terraform, bdd

Is there a way I can test the terraform version that is installed/being used using terraform-compliance?

Use case - Terraform version is set to "1.0.0" . If the version is accidentally changed and committed, I want to to have a test scenario that will check if the version is still "1.0.0" and not something else

Problem( potential ) - The "terraform_version" is not under the "root_module" but above it
The terraform version is locked to "1.0.0" in the version.tf file. This is what the plan.out.json looks like -
`"prior_state": { "format_version": "0.1", "terraform_version": "1.0.0", "values": { "root_module": {`

Is there a scenario statement that i can use to test it?

Example-
`Scenario: Check if terraform is running on the right versioned Given I have terraform version defined Then the terraform_version must be "1.0.0"`
Output -
Syntax Error Cannot find step definition for step 'Then the terraform_version must be "1.0.0"

I am expecting to have a version number test

Comment: The Terraform version number in the prior state is the version of Terraform that created _the previous state snapshot_, so I don't think that's the information you want anyway. If you run `terraform version -json` then you can get a JSON representation of the current Terraform executable's version information, but that's independent of anything written in your configuration. If you want to test something that's written in the configuration then it would help to share the relevant parts of that configuration so it's clearer what you are trying to test against.